# Insert JS in CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking for a way insert JS into web page using CSS file, in Opera. In Internet Explorer [I tested it on 5.5,6,7,8] it's possible using `behaviour` property.

```
behavior: url(file.htc);
```

From my experience it's very useful. Now I need it for Opera.

Comment: What's the underlying design problem you're trying to solve doing this? It just immediately seems as though there may be a better approach available...

Comment: The behavior property is a Microsoft-only one, and as far as I know there is no equivalent property that will work in Firefox, Opera, and other browsers.

Comment: I tried to insert 'background-image: url("svg.svg")', and script tag into SVG file. But I found that opera execute scripts in SVG only if I call it through <embd> tag.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Give some more detail like the JS you want to use, and what browsers you actually want to target...

Comment: @Dani-Br: Assuming that comment of yours is all true, it's probably because the Opera devs realise that allowing CSS to execute JavaScript in any way is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such equivalent feature in Opera.

You'll have to find another way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour property is a proprietary to internet explorer. So it's unlikely you will find an equivalent.

However interestingly, looking through an [old W3 working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-becss-19990804#behavior), it is proposed as a standard - but I haven't seen anything about other browsers actually supporting it nor an equivalent.

On a side note:
The behaviour property is very useful for "patching" internet explorer to enhance old browsers with newer features e.g. adding css3 rounded corner support etc. But at this time, because it is non-standard I would not recommend using it for anything other than adding support to outdated browsers.